# How do I use local variables from another function in python?

Tags: python

```
def foo():

    results = []
    res = a + b
    results.append(res)
    res = a - b
    results.append(res)
    foo2()

def foo2():

    res = c + d
    results.append(res)
    res = c - d
    results.append(res)
```

gives an error "results" is not an global variable. how can I append "res" value to "results" from other function foo2()

Comment: This code does not execute. Please provide a [**Minimal, Complete, Verifiable** Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Learn how to return values from a function and how to pass arguments to a function.

Answer (score 1):

The code needs to call a function to get any result. List `results` is within function `foo()`'s scope, but when we call function `foo2()` from `foo()`, `foo2()` also needs to know what `results` is, so we pass the `results` list as a parameter to `foo2()`.

Since we want to print a variable (list `results`) that was defined within a function, we need to pass that variable back to the calling functions with `return`.

A complete runnable example:

```
# example values
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
d = 4

def foo():
    results = []
    res = a + b
    results.append(res)
    res = a - b
    results.append(res)
    return foo2(results)  # pass results as an argument to other function

def foo2(results):
    """ this function receives results parameter """
    res = c + d
    results.append(res)
    res = c - d
    results.append(res)
    return results

result = foo()
print result   # [3, -1, 7, -1]
```